# google map with contact information in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, google-maps

Dears;

could anyone provide me with HTML code to make the same google map section of the below website for wordpress ?

https://www.wujha.com/en

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code snippet, it's with your actual address. I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```html
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3656.317776446738!2d58.454541315360835!3d23.592933700689485!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x3e91ff293b246a53%3A0xcad73ee276cac591!2sWUJHA+REAL+ESTATE+DEVELOPERS!5e0!3m2!1sen!2s!4v1553247749123" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you dear , I need to include the information in this code as well as the above website , could you please help me ? Thank you

Comment: @mhdpower which information you want to include in this?

Comment: @HassanSiddiqui Get in touch information , as same as wujha.com/en

Comment: @mhdpower I think you want to change your current map with google map rest of the UI will be same, correct me if I'm wrong?